# How to edit the finger swipe's minimum distance gesture to UIScrollView start scrolling?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, swift4, xcode9

How to edit the minimum distance range that i have to swipe the finger on  device to UIScrollView start scrolling? In my case, I am using a horizontal scrolling to change between Views that act like pages. I want to decrease the minimum value because a kind of ugly delay is happening when scrolling (the scroll delays to start). I can provide more information if necessary. Thanks in advance.

[The swipe gesture that i mean](https://www.google.com.br/search?biw=1280&bih=607&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=swipe+gesture+gif&oq=swipe+gesture+gif&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3567.9581.0.9695.7.7.0.0.0.0.854.1065.2-1j6-1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.MA8IPNDHu2k#imgrc=Gds6KiJmYwZjkM:)

Comment: Ok then provide more info

Comment: @zombie what you need? couldn't you understanding anything? sorry for the bad english. I've added a link of a GIF example